# Select distinct from after certain date

Tags: sql

I have a DB with 3 tables: `classes`, `teacher` and `taught`:

> classes
>
> - ID (classNum)
> - title (classesType)
> - cost (classesCost)
>
> teacher
>
> - unique int (teacherNum)
>
> taught
>
> - classNum (foreign key)
> - teacherNum (foreign key)
> - date field (classdate)

I need to write a query in SQL that will return a list of unique classes that were taught on since Aug 6 2015 sorted from most expensive to least expensive

Would I use distinct for this? To get all unique results or leverage the foreign keys.

will this work?

Comment: Welcome to Super User. We are not a script writing service. We expect users to tell us what they have tried so far (including the code they are using) and where they're stuck so that we can help with specific problems. Questions that only ask for code are too broad and are likely to be [put on hold or closed](http://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions). Please read [How do I ask a good question?](http://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Looks like a homework question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, something like:

```
SELECT DISTINCT * 
FROM classes
WHERE ID IN 
(SELECT classNum  FROM taught WHERE date = CONVERT(...,Aug 6 2015 ))
ORDER BY cost ASC
```

Comment: I just did this

Comment: could I also do WHERE date >= Convert(datetime, '2010-11-01’ ) what is the use of the ellipsis here?

Comment: Yes, possibly WHERE date >= Convert(datetime, '2010-11-01’,  112  ) https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ms187928%28v=sql.120%29.aspx

Answer (score -1):

I've used the following construct ...

CAST(FLOOR(CAST(@date as FLOAT)) as DateTime);

this removes the time from the date by converting it to a float and truncating off the "time" part, which is the decimal of the float.

Looks a little clunky but works well on a large dataset (~100,000 rows) I use repeatedly throughout the day.

Comment: SELECT distinct(CONVERT(varchar(10), {your date column}, 111)) 
FROM {your table name}